# Configure multiple commands on key combination

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In Visual Studio Code, `File > Preferences > Keyboard` Shortcuts Menu, I can override default bindings in keybindings.json. But how can I add multiple bindings on a key? I wan't to do something like save as well as format code on press of `ctrl+s`

`{ "key": "ctrl+s","command": "workbench.action.files.save,editor.action.format" }`

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know that is currently not possible as the first keyboard shortcut that matches wins (searched from bottom to top) and no further shortcuts are evaluated - from the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_keyboard-rules):

> When a key is pressed:
>
> - the rules are evaluated from bottom to top.
> - the first rule that matches, both the key and in terms of when, is accepted.
> - no more rules are processed.
> - if a rule is found and has a command set, the command is executed.

That said, it seems that someone had the same desire and wrote an extension for that - see [gyuha.format-on-save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gyuha.format-on-save)
However I did not test that extension myself so I can't tell you how well it works

Comment: One thing to point out is that commands can be context-specific (see the `when` clause)--in the default keymap note that keys are bound multiple times based on context. But it is true that currently a key mapping can run only one command.

Comment: Yeah `when` is mentioned in the rules above `the first rule that matches, both the key and in terms of when, is accepted`

Comment: The link to that extension is dead. I've found another [Format on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WinstonFeng.FormatonSave) in the marketplace, and it seems that the one you found is now hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/gyuha/vscode-format-on-save). Like you, I haven't tested them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the when clause as shown here where I hook up ctrl+enter to only case where .py[thon] script editor extension is active which is similar to the ctrl+enter file | preferences | keyboard shortcuts enabled by .R script editor extension.

```
[    
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "python.execSelectionInTerminal",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'python'"
    }
]
```